# How to reset a compute module stuck in kernel panic?

Tags: hardware, compute-module

My compute module boots up into kernel panic, I can't get a console to enter commands to exit, stop, reset, anything. I'm also a newbie, I know very little about Linux, so I rely heavily on eBooks, online posts and publications and newsletters sent by those in the know; and follow their suggestions and/or instructions.

So the information that I seek, is so that I can reuse the 'kernel panicked' compute module, until I get the programming steps right.

If it can't be undone, I will have to move on and buy another compute module, and be very careful to follow each step to the letter of the instructions, which, by the way, I thought I did; but, (here I am)

Comment: Assuming CM does mean Compute Module, then it should just be a case of reflashing the eMMC. This guide outlines how : https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/cm-emmc-flashing.md

Comment: I thank you for your reply and suggestion, however I have been doing exactly that (following the instructions in the: raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/...) over and over again, using a notebook pc running Windows 8.1, a notebook pc running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and a raspberry pi model b+; without success.